# node.js async parallel function returns a single result several times

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to upload several files in parallel using node.js's async module.  My code looks like:

```
// fileArr is an array of objects. each object contains the attributes of the file to be uploaded - filename, path, destination path, etc.

// toUpload is an array to which i push all the functions i want to execute with async.parallel

  for (i=0; i<fileArr.length; i++) {
    var src = fileArr[i]['path']
    var dest = fileArr[i]['dest']
    var fn = function(cb) { self.upload(src, dest, headers, function(err, url) { 
      cb(null, url)   
    })  
  }
  toUpload.push(fn) 
  } // for loop ends here

async.parallel(toUpload, function(err, results) {
  console.log('results: ' + results)
})
```

My problem:  for n = the number of functions in toUpload, the results array callback contains the result from the last parallel task in the array, n times.  I can't figure this out.  it seems like every function should return its own callback with (null, url) to the parallel function.

also - when i try calling the self.upload function with the definitions of src and dest directly:

```
self.upload(fileArr[i]['path'], fileArr[i]['dest'], headers, function(err, url) {
  cb(null, url)
})
```

i get a error saying "cannot read property 'path' of undefined".  so, fileArr[i] is undefined.  why does this happen?  i feel like there is some weirdness with assignments and scope going on...

if it's not immediately obvious from the question (and the code), i'm pretty new to programming..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, this is essentially:

```
var src, dest
for (i=0; i<fileArr.length; i++) {
  src = fileArr[i]['path']
  dest = fileArr[i]['dest']
  var fn = function(cb) {
    self.upload(src, dest, headers, function(err, url) { 
      cb(null, url)   
  })  
}
```

which may make it clearer that by the time your `fn` function is called, the for loop has finished, so `src`, and `dest` will have their final loop value for every call to `fn`.

Similarly, for `self.upload(fileArr[i]['path'], fileArr[i]['dest'], ...`, by the time your function runs, the value of `i === fileArr.length` because the for-loop has finished.

The easiest solution for this would be to use `async.map` instead.

```
async.map(
  fileArr,
  function(file, callback){
    self.upload(file['src'], file['dest'], headers, function(err, url){
      callback(null, url);
    });
  },
  function(err, results) {
    console.log('results: ' + results)
  }
)
```

I'm passing `null` as the error because that is what you are doing in your example, but you should probably not be discarding errors since they might be important.

Comment: ok, that helps, but wait.. i'm pushing fn into my parallel array for each iteration of the for loop.  so each function in the parallel array should have different arguments, right?  since the values of src and dest are different every time i push the function to array?

Comment: Each instance of `fn` is a new function, but it references values in the outer function scope. It will not use those values until the function is actually executed, and in this case by the time it runs, the values have been changed by the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yup! I updated the example, that was just a copy/paste error.

Comment: thanks a lot man.  great explanation - just re-implemented using .map and it worked perfectly.